# Why is exception "Undefined variable" thrown out?

Tags: php, phpunit

I have two php files. The first one `func.php` contains a function, and the second one `funcTest.php` is for testing the function.
First:

```php
<?php
    function func(int $a, int $b, $data) {
          echo "$a, $b, $data";
          return $a + $b;
    }
```

Second:

```php
<?php
    require_once "PHPUnit/Autoload.php";
    use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
    
    $data = "Some data";

    var_dump($data);
    
    final class funcTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
        public function testFunc() {
            require "func.php";
            $this->assertEquals(3, func(1, 2, $data));
        }
    }
```

The problem is when I run test using phpunit in cmd, I get these errors:

> There was 1 error:
>
> 1. funcTest::testFunc Undefined variable: data
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\someproject\funcTest.php:12

P.S. I've found similar questions on SO and other forums, but none of those helped me. So please DO NOT CLOSE OR DISS MY QUESTION.

Comment: Have you read through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and ?

Comment: Variable scope is one of the very basics of any programming language. I suggest you thoroughly read the question that Nigel linked, you'll literally need that knowledge everywhere.

Comment: The combination of `require_once "PHPUnit/Autoload.php";`, `use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;`, and `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` makes no sense. You are mixing different versions of PHPUnit.

Comment: @NigelRen oh I see. I've tried to write require "func.php" in the global scope of funcTest.php file and now it works! Thank you.

Comment: @NigelRen will you write the answer? I'll mark it as the solving of my problem

Comment: But why was I dissed? That's wrong to just diss every single question that you don't like, you whoever did this

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned by others, its good to read up on variable scoping

```
$data = "Some data";

var_dump($data);

final class funcTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function testFunc($data) // <---- You need to pass the $data variable into the method
    
    {
        require "func.php";
        $this->assertEquals(3, func(1, 2, $data));
    }
} 

// instantiate and call the method
$test = new funcTest;
$test->testFunc($data); //<--- Pass in the $data variable when calling the method
```